# Altair: fix title position for interactive() chart

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I am using Altair to create a `mark_point` plot with the slightly strange combination (as far as I can tell via searching) of `clip=False` and `.interactive()`.  This allows me to pan and zoom the axes while the points themselves are allowed to leave the axes bounding box and stay visible.

An unintuitive side effect of this is that the plot title moves its position to get out of the way of the points as they leave the axes - to the point where the title will in fact leave the screen altogether if I pan down far enough.  **I would like to have the title stay in a fixed position regardless of the contents of a mark moving around outside the axes.**

It seems like this should be possible via `configure_title` but I can't figure it out.  The `frame` keyword controls the reference for the anchor, but there is no option for using screen pixels instead of the data.  I checked the Vega documentation for Title and it does not appear like there are any relevant properties that Altair is not controlling.  Weirdly, the axis labels **don't** have this problem: they stay in their place even as the points move over them.  I would like the title to behave the same way.

Here is a very simple MRE that creates a plot with this problem:

```
    import altair as alt
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.linspace(0, 4, 100)})
    df['y'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df['x'])

    chart = alt.Chart(df, title='TITLE HERE').mark_point(filled=True, size=100, clip=False).encode(
        x='x:Q', y='y:Q').interactive()
    chart = chart.configure_title(frame='group')
```

The obvious workaround is to not use a chart title and instead use a `mark_text` with `clip=False` and fixed pixel coordinates at the top of the window to manually make my own title, but I would rather not have to jump through that hoop every time I make a plot.

Comment: Since this is really an issue in VegaLite I added the corresponding tag, but if you don't get a response here, you might want to report it on the VegaLite issue tracker as an inconsistency between how the axis labels and title work.